# How to display a hidden field value after calling location.reload() in ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

Display a hidden field value after calling `location.reload()` .

```
var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
                url: "my url",//locating to another project action method which is already deployed and running in server
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data
        });     
ajaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {

            location.reload();//reloading page
            $('#imageUploadScs').show();//displaying hidden field after reloading page

        });
```

Comment: any commands written after location.reload() will not happen, because you reloaded the page before they can execute. So you start from scratch. Your logic needs a rethink

Comment: you need to persist the value..e.g. in `localstorage` and then get back it on reload

Comment: Doing a page reload defeats the purpose of using ajax

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Why you use ajax?

Comment: @charlietfl you can... check if local storage is not empty, if it is empty then input stays hidden if it is not empty, use localstorage and delete localstorage, simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reload, the page *reloads*.  So any changes you've made to the state of the page are lost.

So you have two options:

1. Don't reload.  This is the preferred option.  You're already using AJAX, simply update the state of the page as needed.  You shouldn't have to reload at all.
2. Before reloading, persist some flag somewhere (local storage?  cookie?  something of that nature) which indicates that the field should be shown.  In the page's start-up code (you're using jQuery, so I assume a `document.ready` handler would be standard here) check for that flag and show the field.

The first option is certainly preferred.  But the second option might *structurally* look something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var shouldShowField = getPersistedFlag();
    if (shouldShowField) {
        $('#imageUploadScs').show();
    }
});

// elsewhere...
ajaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {
    setPersistedFlag();
    location.reload();
});
```

The implementations of `getPersistedFlag` and `setPersistedFlag` would be what's described above.  They would read and write whatever data you want to persist to whatever storage mechanism you choose.  (Any of which have many examples available.)

If it seems like that's over-complicating the effort, you're probably right.  Which is why the first option of not reloading the page in the first place is preferred.